# How to change deleteAction in Jtable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

Please tell me how to change the setting `actions.deleteAction` with functions `deleteConfirmation` that would not change the source ?
Thanks in advance!

```
$('#pages-table').jtable({
    title: 'Birds',
    paging: true,
    pageSize: 15, 
    sorting: true, 
    defaultSorting: 'name ASC',
    selecting: true,
    multiselect: true,
    selectingCheckboxes: true,
    selectOnRowClick: false,
    actions: {
        listAction: '/aima-admin/?plugin=pages&ajax=yes&action=jtable&jtable=list&catid=1&lang=en',
        deleteAction: '/aima-admin/?plugin=pages&ajax=yes&action=jtable&jtable=delete'
    },
    deleteConfirmation: function(data) {
        data.deleteConfirmMessage = '<p>Удалить</p><input type="radio" value="page" name="delPage">Страницу <input type="radio" value="translate" name="delPage">Перевод';
    },
```

Get the scoop function of the source code found _setOption. 
It is the idea should be to establish such an option. 
But have not figured out how to use it. Can anyone experienced this?

Comment: Explain what you want and add the code you are currently using, so we can at least help you.

Comment: Here's the code. I want to change the url in the function "deleteConfirmation". But it does not work.